# how can i propagate the changes from mercurial to my production web server?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, distributed

I've a PHP app and i'm using Mercurial as Revision Control.

I want to code a bash script or something like that that help me to update the content of my web server.

I mean, the idea would like to update all the files that i've changed in a changeset (maybe through SCP), to the production server. If i could get the files that had changed (absolute paths) i could make SCP without problems.

Also, a solution would be to get the absolute paths to the files that are printed with hg stat

But that would be before commit.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Clone a copy of your repository on your web server
2. Use rsync to keep your web server directories in sync with a repository on a separate server

Comment: I'm using Rsync right now. I think that just cloning the repo and keeping it up to date would be a good option. Just need to tune some things. Thanks Nick.

Comment: +1: `rsync` is your friend. And so is Mercurial. The one thing they don't address is revision control/synchronizing your database, but that tends to be a per-project solution.